# NullPointerException InAppBilling.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:356)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have implemented In-App Billing in my project  but some times it give the following NullPointerException IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow() method. currently i m using reserved ID's for testing and apk is not signed.

```
02-01 01:53:56.097: E/AndroidRuntime(9314): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 01:53:56.097: E/AndroidRuntime(9314):     at com.example.app.InAppBilling.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:356)
02-01 01:53:56.097: E/AndroidRuntime(9314):     at com.example.app.InAppBilling.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:307)
02-01 01:53:56.097: E/AndroidRuntime(9314):     at com.example.app.MYTabActivity$4.onClick(MYTabActivity.java:418)
02-01 01:53:56.097: E/AndroidRuntime(9314):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage
.
```

.
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *may* help you: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41407

```
// in IapHelper.java line 357
if (listener != null)
   listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
flagEndAsync(); // Added
return; // Added
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This solved my problem that i am facing from two days.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that my edit is correct, since we don't call `flagEndAsync()` if the call succeeds, I'm not familiar with the rest of the class though. It may be better to put it in a `finally` statement or something similar. Open to others edits for sure.

Comment: flagEndAsync() is must it will end the Async operation and for next time if we try purchase it will not throw "llegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress."

Comment: @Soup in handleActivityResult it's already called. Why do i need to call it again?

Answer (score -5):

`NullPointerException` will come when you call `method or varible on null refference.`

Make all your refference with Null Check.

EX:

IabHelper labHelper = null;

if you call

```
labHelper.getSomething(); // since labHelper is null this will cause NullPointerException
```

Some tips to avoid NullPointerException

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/avoid-null-pointer-exception-in-java.html